# How to handle different return values from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a function in Python that can return different things. How do I handle this correctly? I have something like this:

```
def function():
    #do something, when everything went allright do:
    return (int, int, int, int)
    # if something went wrong
    return False

x, y, z, a = function()
```

How do I make this work when the function returns `False`?

Comment: Rather than returning `False`, *raise an error*. Then it's as simple as `try: x, y, z, a = function(); except SomeError: do_whatever()`. *Don't* return "error codes" from Python functions.

Comment: You would need an intermediate step the way you are designing your function: `tmp = function(); if tmp: x,y,z,a = tmp`.  I agree with jonrsharpe: the natural way to handle errors in python is to raise an exception, and use a try-catch statement to handle the error where appropriate.

Comment: What do you want `x, y, z, a` to be set to if something goes wrong in the  function? Depending on your use case, you could return four `0`s, four `False` values or four `None` values, etc, e.g.: `return [False] * 4`

Comment: Or assign a single value to the function and check whether it's a tuple or a bool and unpack the tuple later

Answer (score 3):

In general, try to avoid this as it makes your functions cumbersome to work with. Raise an exception in case something went wrong, maybe a custom exception that has a "error_message" attribute if you need that, or something.

But you *can* use a function like yours with

```
result = function()

if result:
    x, y, z, a = result
else:
    panic()
```

Comment: That would definitely *work*, but if I saw that code I would immediately put into effect the latter half of, "When you're writing code, pretend the person maintaining it is a homicidal psychopath who knows where you sleep".